# Access export formula to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to export the below string to excel, it appears as text when pasted but when I go into the cell and then out it then knows its a formula and then carries it out. Is there any way to automatically show the formula result?

```
=HYPERLINK("\\192.198.0.9\folder1\folder2\"&SUBSTITUTE("data 1"," ","_")&".pdf",SUBSTITUTE("data 1"," ","_")&".pdf")
```

Thanks.

Comment: in excel the above code is what i see in the cell. As soon as I enter the cell and the exit the cell the formula the calculates and gives me my result.

Comment: yes thats correct, a VBA solution would be great. Thanks.